# Discord.py Bot Restarts After Every Loop w/ No Error

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've tried to ask this question on the discord.py Discord server and got no suggestions.

I have a discord.py bot and it does a fairly intensive loop every 15 minutes where it has to go to an API many times (about 50 API requests). For some reason, after successfully completing the loop, it restarts and I get the on_ready function triggered. Actually, I don't even know if the bot is restarting, because there's no error message. I just see the on_ready message print out after every loop.

As my bot gets added to more guilds, the loop gets more intense. When my bot was in ~20 guilds, it would restart like this occasionally...but more like once a day or something like that. Now with 50 guilds, it's every 15 minutes.

But there's no errors anywhere. I have no idea where to start with diagnosing what's happening with no error message.

EDIT - Adding on_ready code:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready.")

    run = False

    while run is False:

        minutes = dt.now().minute
        if (int(minutes) > 12 and int(minutes < 18)) or (int(minutes) > 27 and int(minutes < 33)) or (int(minutes) > 42 and int\
(minutes < 48)) or (int(minutes) > 57 and int(minutes <= 59)) or (int(minutes) >= 0 and int(minutes <= 3)):

            print("BAD TIME %s"%(minutes))
            time.sleep(180)

        else:

            run = True

    if not transactions.is_running():
        transactions.start()

    else:

        pass
```

transactions.start() is the loop

Comment: could you share your code snippet? i doubt anyone can diagnose without anything to go off of

Comment: Added it in...not sure that's enough to help since I'm not sure where the breakdown is. The loop code has a lot more going on so I'm not sure where to even start with that.

Comment: My suspicion is that you aren't asynchronously sleeping since you are using `time.sleep(180)`. Take a look at [asyncio.sleep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping). Also, you probably shouldn't do this in `on_ready()`. Take a look at [discord.ext.tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) and make it into an invoke-able function. Then, you can call that function in `on_ready()` so it's not directly running inside `on_ready()`.
Also your if statement can be something like `if int(minutes) in [ # your list of unacceptable minutes]`.

Comment: I read your code wrong cuz I skimmed through it, my bad. It seems like you are using the `discord.ext.tasks`, but doing the minute check should be in your task function, not in on_ready.

Comment: I am worried cause the bot can't perform other functions while it is doing the loop task. If I add the minute check in the on_ready, it just will process that ONCE and then start the loop when it's ok to start and then every 15 minutes after that will not run into the bad minutes.

If I add the check in the loop task itself, it will hang every 15 minutes forever, I believe? I should also note that the bot restarts regardless of whether it actually is sleeping for the 3 minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237182/discussion-between-shark-and-andyg555).